# References for pronunciation of different verb forms

Tags: prononciation, conjugaison, ressources

I'm a beginner in French and I'm learning pronunciation in French with [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1438072813) book. Would anybody come up with any good books/resources which contains the rules of pronunciation of different verb (in each conjugation) forms?

Comment: [French verb morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_verb_morphology) seems to partially answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a book, but an excellent resource for pronunciation guidelines is [forvo.com](http://forvo.com/languages/fr/). You can search for almost any word with pronunciations recorded and submitted by (supposedly*) native speakers.

### Some examples for a verb (jouer - all present tense forms + past participle, imperfect and future):

- [joue](http://forvo.com/word/joue/#fr)
- [joues](http://forvo.com/word/joues/#fr)
- [jouons](http://forvo.com/word/jouons/#fr)
- [jouez](http://forvo.com/word/jouez/#fr)
- [jouent](http://forvo.com/word/jouent/#fr)
- [joué](http://forvo.com/word/jou%C3%A9/#fr)
- [jouais](http://forvo.com/word/jouais/#fr)
- [jouerai](http://forvo.com/word/jouerai/#fr)

---

As you can probably here, there is little to distinguish between quite a few of the verb forms, especially joue, joues and jouent.

(* I say supposedly because, as far as I'm aware, you don't have to be native. It's always a good idea to try and find more than one recording / cross reference just to make sure you're not learning a non-standard accent etc.)

Comment: I did not understand OP was asking for audio files but rules of pronunciation. [Here](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/conjugations/) are some good audio files. But the method OP uses already has a CD with audio files.

Comment: @Laure I don't think he was asking for audio files, but you can learn the rules quite well just by hearing plenty of examples.